# For a stochastic system, should we optimize its time average cost or total cost? What is the difference between the two goals?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mean, optimization, stochastic-processes

For a stochastic system, the time average cost like:
$ \lim_{T \to \infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}\mathbb{E}\{cost(t)\}$
and total cost like:
$ \lim_{T \to \infty}\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}\mathbb{E}\{cost(t)\}$.
If our goal is cost minimization, which optimization objective should be used?

Comment: Time average cost; the limit of total cost in many systems is $\infty$, and you can't optimize that away (again in many systems.)